# first of type selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

How would I target the first .list-group-title in this example? Ideally this would work for other instances where the .list-group-title could be the first, second or third div but I always want to target the first .list-group-title.

```
<div class="content-sidebar">
  <div class="list-group-divider">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-title">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-divider">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-title">…</div>
  <div id="ember1956" class="ember-view">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-title">…</div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
.list-group-title:first-of-type
```

which doesn't work and I've tried:

```
.list-group-title:nth-child(2)
```

but this won't solve it if it is not the 2nd div in another example.

Is there any way to acheive this?

Comment: `:first-of-type != :first-of-class`, where `:first-of-class` doesn't exist - unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS doesn't contain a `first-of-class` type of selector. What you can do however, is do the opposite: target all but the first occurrence, thus effectively styling the first one in reverse.

```css
.list-group-title {
  background: red;
}

.list-group-title ~ .list-group-title {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-sidebar">
  <div class="list-group-divider">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-title">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-divider">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-title">…</div>
  <div id="ember1956" class="ember-view">…</div>
  <div class="list-group-item list-group-title">…</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, as same as I attempt to answer. You are faster :)

Comment: However, this will only work if the OP wants to add some styling to the first element. If he however wants, for example, to style the second element (not the first and third one), this won't work. Nevertheless +1

Comment: @Vucko You can easily expand this solution to target only the second occurrence.

Comment: @Nit can you provide an example?

Comment: @Vucko http://jsfiddle.net/2fa6fkfv/

Comment: @Nit I see what you did there. Nice solution, tnx :)

Comment: using multiples of `~` (if follows)

Comment: Also note that in some particular cases you can achieve that with `:first-child`. Of course that only works on first child of a given class inside their parent.

Comment: @Nit thanks for that very clever solution.